# Akka Streams Kafka error handling - access to element that caused the problem in Kafka Producer

Tags: akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I see for example exception like this:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 10000190 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.
```

Is there a way to know more about a ProducerRecord that caused this exception?

In `Supervisor` or `recoverWith` I have only info about exception.
I can't wrap anything with `try catch`, because I'm using built in Kafka Flow or Kafka Sink. Probably I'd need to give up with this integration and use Kafka producer manually, because I see no other solution.

Comment: Not sure it's possible, since you're getting the exception *while deserializing*, that is , before the `ProducerRecord ` is created, so you won't have access to the record itself, I'd look for the partition/offset instead.
Incidentally, 10 megabytes messages, kafka does not like messages that are that large.

Comment: I know, that is only example. No matter what exception is thrown I have no business context of this exception, so it is difficult to figure out what goes wrong.